# AllowAnonymous not working ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a project that I created using VS 2019 and enabled Azure Auth during the setup for the project. I have an issue in which when setting a controller to `[AllowAnonymous]` the app still asks for the user to authenticate.

I have checked IIS and Allow Anonymous is enabled and am pretty at a loss after a day and a half of googling. Hoping someone can help.

For good measure, here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            //services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

            // Use SQL Database if in Azure, otherwise, use SQLite
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProdLibsDbContext")));

            else
                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContext")));

            // Automatically perform database migration
            services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<AppDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there were two issues.

(1) Include `.AddAuthorization()`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

(2) Run the MVC middleware

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ... )
{
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: .AddAuthorization(); in the correct location worked. Because I am using ASP.net Core 3.0 useMvc() is deprecated for UseEndpoints(); as per MS's documentation. However worked like a charm, thanks you!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about useMvc!

Comment: Hello @Amraj, have you managed to do this with UseEndpoints, or you stick to the old UseMvc and EnableEndpointRouting = false? I have related issue with IAuthorizationFilter with OnAuthorization not triggered.